# JS - Merge objects when multiple keys have same value while summing other values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Here is my array :

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "1120"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "12003"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "34706"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "6158"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "3702"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "158"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client2",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "80"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client2",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "17200"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client3",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "393"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client3",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "4073"
  }
]
```

I want to merge objects when Date && Client && Product are the same.
The solution would be reuseable for other filters such as merging similar arrays of objects when for instance Organisation && Client are the same, or Product only, etc..

The expected output is this :

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "13123"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "34706"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "6316"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "3702"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client2",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "80"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client2",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "17200"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client3",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "4466"
  }
]
```

i've tried to use a mix of `reduce` and `findIndex` but it doesn't seem to work as it only returns 1st value and not summing them if multiple.

```
var data = obj.reduce((acc, v) => {
    const index = acc.findIndex(o => {
        return o["Date"] === v["Date"] &&
            o["Product"] === v["Product"] &&
            o["Client"] === v["Client"]
    });

    if (index >= 0) {
        acc[index]["Quantity"] = 0;
        acc[index]["Quantity"] += Number(v["Quantity"]);
    }
    else {
        acc.push(v);
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(data);

return data;
```

EDIT :
My code was good, i simply had to change if statement, i don't know why.

```
if (index >= 0) {
                var originalQty = Number(acc[index]["Quantity"]);
                originalQty += Number(v["Quantity"]);
                acc[index]["Quantity"] = originalQty.toString();
            }
```

Might have been an issue between my processed obj which had numbers in strings, and what i wanted to return.
It simply couldn't math strings together.
Though i wonder why it did not return simple numbers in strings appended...

Anyway, thanks everyone for your fast answers !
Each have good aswers !

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` like so - it's easier to deal with an object first, then get the values of that object as an array.

```js
const arr = [{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"1120"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"12003"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"34706"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"6158"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"3702"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"158"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client2","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"80"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client2","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"17200"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client3","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"393"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client3","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"4073"}];

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, { Date, Organisation, Client, Product, Quantity }) => {
  const s = `${Date}-${Client}-${Product}`;
  a[s] = a[s] || { Date, Organisation, Client, Product, Quantity: 0 };
  a[s].Quantity += +Quantity;
  return a;
}, {})).map(({ Quantity, ...r }) => ({ ...r, Quantity: Quantity.toString() }));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

<sub>(There's an extra `map` to convert `Quantity` to a string, because I converted `Quantity` to a number to add them together. Remove it if you wish, but `Quantity` in the output will be a number.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can create function that takes your data and array of keys and then use `reduce` method to create object with merged values and return `Object.values` that will be array of merged values.

```js
const data = [{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"1120"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"12003"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"34706"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"6158"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"3702"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"158"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client2","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"80"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client2","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"17200"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client3","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"393"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client3","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"4073"}]


function merge(data, keys) {
  const obj = data.reduce((r, e) => {
    const key = keys.map(k => e[k]).join('|');
    if (!r[key]) r[key] = { ...e,
      Quantity: +e.Quantity
    };
    else r[key].Quantity += +e.Quantity;
    return r;
  }, {})

  return Object.values(obj)
}

console.log(merge(data, ['Date', 'Client', 'Product']))
console.log(merge(data, ['Organisation', 'Client']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic function which takes an input array and an array keys to merge. Create an accumulator object which will have every unique combination of the properties in the `keys` array.

```
function merge(arr, keys) {
  const group = arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
    const unique = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
    if(acc[unique])
      acc[unique].Quantity += +o.Quantity;
    else
      acc[unique] = { ...o, Quantity: +o.Quantity };
    return acc;
  }, {})

 return Object.values(group)
}
```

For the `['Date', 'Client', 'Product']` properties, this is what the `group` object will look like.

```
{
  "2019.07.08|Client1|Pen": {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": 13123
  },
  "2019.07.08|Client1|Ruler": {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": 34706
  },
  "2019.07.07|Client1|Ruler": {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": 6316
  },
  "2019.07.07|Client1|Pen": {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": 3702
  },
  "2019.07.07|Client2|Pen": {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client2",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": 80
  },
  "2019.07.07|Client2|Ruler": {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client2",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": 17200
  },
  "2019.07.08|Client3|Pen": {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client3",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": 4466
  }
}
```

Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of this object as an array

Here's a snippet:

```js
const arr = [{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"1120"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"12003"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"34706"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"6158"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"3702"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client1","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"158"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client2","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"80"},{"Date":"2019.07.07","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client2","Product":"Ruler","Quantity":"17200"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client3","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"393"},{"Date":"2019.07.08","Organisation":"A","Client":"Client3","Product":"Pen","Quantity":"4073"}]

function merge(arr, keys) {
  const group = arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
    const unique = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
    
    if(acc[unique])
      acc[unique].Quantity += +o.Quantity;
    else
      acc[unique] = { ...o, Quantity: +o.Quantity };
      
    return acc;
  }, {})
 
 return Object.values(group)
}

console.log(merge(arr, ['Date', 'Client', 'Product']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work. I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

1. As it iterates, it builds a map based on the values of the unique keys
2. It keeps the Quantity attribute of the map up to data as it iterates through the items.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "1120"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "12003"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "34706"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "6158"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "3702"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "158"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client2",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "80"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.07",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client2",
    "Product": "Ruler",
    "Quantity": "17200"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client3",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "393"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019.07.08",
    "Organisation": "A",
    "Client": "Client3",
    "Product": "Pen",
    "Quantity": "4073"
  }
]

var fieldsToUniqueOn = ["Client", "Product", "Organisation"]

document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(mergeData(data, fieldsToUniqueOn), null, 4);

function mergeData(data, uniqueOn) {
  var merged = {}
  data.forEach(item => {
      var key = fieldsToUniqueOn.map(field => item[field]).join("");
      if (merged[key] == null) {
          merged[key] = { ...item, Quantity: 0 }
      }
      merged[key]["Quantity"] += +item["Quantity"]
  });
  return Object.values(merged);
}
```

```html
<pre id="data">
</pre>
```